# How do I set a dynamic image in WP7 LongListSelector in GroupHeaderTemplate?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I am using the LongListSelector from the Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit.

For each group I would like to show a small group related icon, in the group header.

Group A
   Item 1
   Item 2
   Item 3

Each of the items have the same key, and are grouping correctly. And each item has the same image. But when I change my GroupHeaderTemplate from the key to something else. It doesn't seem to handle this correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you see examples that use a "Group" object which is based on the `IGrouping<TKey, T>` style object which implements IEnumberable and has a single Key property.

However there is no reason why your group object can't also have a whole range of other properties like "Name" and "ImageSource" whatever that you will be able to bind in the group item templates.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ these two articles for insights on `LongListSelector`

1. [WP7 LongListSelector in depth | Part1: Visual structure and API](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api)
2. [WP7 LongListSelector in depth | Part2: Data binding scenarios](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios)

Comment: Yep, those are the things one I'm working from. He is using the key for grouping.

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>

I want to be able to do something like

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us some more information with regards to your source data and the XAMl that you're using. It sounds like you need to expose a path to the image you want for each group and then bind the Image element in the GroupHeaderTemplate to that property.